# How to add resource_access key (realm-management or account) to admin token (fastapi-keycloak)?

Tags: keycloak

I've ran KeyCloak in Docker:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.1 start-dev
```

Then created realm `dialog-test` and client `non-commercial-purchase-public`. Now I need to get admin token:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/realms/dialog-test/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=oCPory1e8KD8xjNlmDSOClKo0I9CNipu' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

But response does not contain `resource_access` key (I need the key because lib [fastapi-keycloak](https://github.com/code-specialist/fastapi-keycloak) [requires it](https://github.com/code-specialist/fastapi-keycloak/blob/master/fastapi_keycloak/api.py#L190)):

```
{
  "exp": 1692114608,
  "iat": 1692114308,
  "jti": "01aae75e-7145-4790-b076-390fde8eb93c",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/dialog-test",
  "sub": "5b2933cb-3dd9-43b7-8890-a1e9d523a08b",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "acr": "1",
  # "resource_access": {"realm-management": "...", "account": "..."} <<- does not returned. I could see only "admin-cli"
  "scope": "profile email",
  "email_verified": false,
  "clientHost": "172.17.0.1",
  "preferred_username": "service-account-admin-cli",
  "clientAddress": "172.17.0.1",
  "client_id": "admin-cli"
}
```

How to add it?

Comment: What roles are you expecting in `resource_access`?

Comment: I've updated the question with `resource_access ` key example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles are usually mapped to the access_token by default(via the `roles` client scope mapper).

For each client, the [role scope mapping](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/22.0.1/server_admin/#_role_scope_mappings) options in keycloak allow you to configure which roles are mapped to the access token e.g all assigned roles of the user (`Full scope allowed=ON`) or you can customise the selection yourself(`Full scope allowed=OFF`).

When [using a service account](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/22.0.1/server_admin/#_service_accounts) to get a token(`grant_type=client_credentials`) for a client you should to set `Full Scope Allowed to ON` for that client so that all roles assigned to the built-in "service user" for the client are mapped to the token.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new client scope (enable "include in token scope"), add a mapper for it based on the information you want to store in resource_access, e.g. realm roles. Then add it to your client scope.
Now the resource_access will be part of your token.